# Multiple Before Elements

Tags: html, css

I have read that it is possible to create a string of before elements by creating a before pseudo element on the before pseudo element before it. What is the syntax for this?

For example something like this:

```
.divMain:before {
    content: 'Number 1';
}

.divMain ::before:before {
    content: 'Number 2';
}
```

and so on.

Comment: My question is slightly different, I want to know if its possible for a pseudo element to have its own pseudo element, not if one element can have multiple pseudo's for itself

Comment: ...which would be the equivalent of having multiple :before elements.

Comment: @Juhana: Not quite - I picked a closer duplicate.